# git submodule version based on tag

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-tag

How do git submodules and tags work, specifically can I use git tags in the host module to change which has the submodule points to?

Lets say that I have a module called `main` and under that, I added a submodule called `dep`. I have just released a new version, so I tag the whole repo with `REL_1`. Life goes on, I  code some more and update the `dep` submodule and commit that to HEAD.

What happens when I checkout `REL_1`? Will `dep` go back to the hash it had when I created the tag?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will dep go back to the hash it had when I created the tag?

It will go back to the hash present when you tagged the whole repo with `REL_1`

A `git submodule update --remote` would then update the submodule (to latest `master` by default)